# jQuery Logic required for select menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a reiszable box using jQuery UI and I then pass the values to a text box. The values can be in either CM or Inches.

The problem I have is when you drag the size after selecting Centimeters from the unit_type box, It reverts back to Inches. I think I just need to rethink the logic on it and remap it all out.

Can anyone help on this..?

Code is...

```
$(function()
{
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        maxWidth:  $("#max_width").val(),
        maxHeight: $("#max_height").val(),
        resize: function() {

            var widthInch = $("#resizable").width() / 200;
            var heightInch = $("#resizable").height() / 200;

            $("#unit_type").change(function()
            {
                var widthCM = $("#resizable").width() / 200 * 2.54;
                var heightCM = $("#resizable").height() / 200 * 2.54;

                $(".width").val(widthCM + '' + ' CM');
                $(".height").val(heightCM + '' + ' CM');
            })

            var widthCM = $("#resziable").width() / 200 * 2.54;
            var heightCM = $("#resizable").height() / 200 * 2.54;

            $(".width").val(widthInch + '' + ' Inches');
            $(".height").val(heightInch + '' + ' Inches');
        }
    });
})
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to see the HTML for the elements that this runs against too. It might also be useful to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo, so people can see what you already have in action.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist fair point - However the jQuery UI Doesnt load with it. I can put the HTML in though, Not a problem

Comment: Can you not link it even in the "Add Resources" panel?

Comment: @StuBlackett Yes it does simply choose jquery as your framework and under it a checkbox says Jquery UI :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in where you are calculating the size. The best solution is to pull this out into a new function and then call that function when the box is resized or the unit is changed. Something like this should work. (You'll have probably modify it to fit your exact markup as I made some assumptions.)

```
$(function()
{
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        maxWidth:  $("#max_width").val(),
        maxHeight: $("#max_height").val(),
        resize: updateSize
    });
})

$("#unit_type").change(updateSize);

function updateSize() {
   unit = $("#unit_type").val();
   if(unit == "in") {
            var widthInch = $("#resizable").width() / 200;
            var heightInch = $("#resizable").height() / 200;

            $(".width").val(widthInch + '' + ' Inches');
            $(".height").val(heightInch + '' + ' Inches');
   } else if(unit == "cm") {
            var widthCM = $("#resizable").width() / 200 * 2.54;
            var heightCM = $("#resizable").height() / 200 * 2.54;

            $(".width").val(widthCM + '' + ' CM');
            $(".height").val(heightCM + '' + ' CM');
   }
}
```